# Tomcat autodeploy doesn't return actual files via HTTP

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

Old file is:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8084
First file
```

I mean - *war-file* contains only one index.jsp page with text "First page":

```
$ jar tf ../app-application/APP.war
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
index.jsp
```

Tomcat's `server.xml` has next components config:

```
    <Host
      name="localhost"
      appBase="/home/user/APP/app-application/"
      unpackWARs="false"
      autoDeploy="true"
      deployOnStartup="false">

      <Context
        path=""
        docBase="APP.war"
        reloadable="true"
      />
```

Then - I copied new *war-file*:

```
$ cat ../tmp/1/index.jsp
Second file

$ cd ../tmp/1/ && jar cf APP.war index.jsp

$ cp APP.war ../../app-application/
cp: overwrite `../../app-application/APP.war'? y
```

And see in log:

```
 INFO: Undeploying context [/APP]
 Jun 3, 2014 1:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
 INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/user/APP/app-application/APP.war
```

Buit - when I'm trying open it with browser - I got old file again:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8084/
First file
```

And only after full Tomcat's reboot - I see new file;

```
$ curl http://localhost:8084
Second file
```

Why? Am I missed something? Tomcat keep it in some cache?

Comment: Does deleting the contents of the work directory help? Also, you shouldn't need to define a `<Context>` if you're using `autodeploy`. It should be **autodeployed**! Try removing the context definition and see what happens.

Comment: @Will No, tried it too
ABout Context - never heard about such config... Thanks - will try tommorow. Do you have any related links, pelase? Regarding config without Context element.

Comment: @Will Thanks a lot - removing <Context> really helps. If you could add this to Answer - I'll `accept` it - this this can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you shouldn't need to define a `<Context>` when you've got `autoDeploy` enabled.

When you have `autoDeploy` as true, `Tomcat` will watch the `appBase` directory for new files and deploy them on a context path named as the `WAR` - EG `app.war` will deploy on the `/app` context path.

You can define a `<Context>` but I think if you do so for an `autoDeploy` `Host` it'll override some of the `Host` settings, and probably cause the breaking of the `autoDeploy`.

Hope this helps,

Will